# "Неужели"

Tags: пунктуация

Отделяется ли запятой "неужели" в начале предложения? "Неужели(,) он смог это сделать?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, не отделяется. "Неужели" - вопросительная частица, такая же как и "разве", "ли".